# Perspective matrix works as orthographic

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics, glm

I try to make perspecive matrix for graphics, this part of code works fine and I have a sphere showing up, but it seems that it doesn't work proparly to create depth, now it is more orthographic.(Actually, I used lots code examples, but nothing ever moved on z Axis) As a base, I used glm perspective function, but with couple changes. And also i attached setting for the camera.
Usful articles would be also great)

[Rendering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oivy5.png)

```
Matrix4 MATRIX::Perspective(float Width, float Height, float ZNear, float ZFar, float fieldOfView) {
    Matrix4 Result = Identity();
    Result[0][0] = (Height / Width) * fieldOfView;
    Result[1][1] = fieldOfView;
    Result[2][2] = -(ZFar + ZNear) / (ZFar - ZNear);
    Result[2][3] = -1.0f;
    Result[3][2] = -(2.0f * ZFar * ZNear) / (ZFar - ZNear);
    return Result;
}
```

```
Camera::Camera()
    : position(Vec3()), fieldOfView(45.0f), forward(Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), up(Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)),
    right(Vec3()), worldUp(up), nearPlane(2.0f), farPlane(50.0f),
    yaw(45.0f), pitch(45.0f), perspective(Matrix4()) {
    perspective = Perspective(APP_INIT_WINDOW_WIDTH,
        APP_INIT_WINDOW_HEIGHT,
        nearPlane, farPlane, fieldOfView);
    UpdateCameraVector();
}
```

This is the function from glm, but it wasn't working completely

```
    template <typename T>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<T, defaultp> perspective
(
    T const & fovy,
    T const & aspect,
    T const & zNear,
    T const & zFar
)
{
    assert(aspect != static_cast<T>(0));
    assert(zFar != zNear);

    T const rad = fovy;
    T const tanHalfFovy = tan(rad / static_cast<T>(2));

    detail::tmat4x4<T, defaultp> Result(static_cast<T>(0));
    Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(1) / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);
    Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(1) / (tanHalfFovy);
    Result[2][2] = - (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
    Result[2][3] = - static_cast<T>(1);
    Result[3][2] = - (static_cast<T>(2) * zFar * zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
    return Result;
}
```

In the result I want the sphere to get more depth.

Comment: What changes were made to glm's perspective function?

Comment: I didn't use tan for the field of view and was like this `Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(1) / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);`

Comment: Actually I might think that there is problem not with projection but with model matrix